# ggplot2 Problems with fill when plotting geom_bar as percent within a facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the following as percentages within each facet_grid:

```
mtcars %>% 
 ggplot(aes(as.factor(vs)))+
 geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(vs) ),  show.legend = F)  +
 facet_grid(as.factor(cyl) ~ as.factor(gear) , scales = "free" )
```

[image]

I tried the following, but it messes up the fill:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(vs)))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(vs), y=..prop.., group=as.factor(cyl)) , show.legend = F ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  facet_grid(as.factor(cyl) ~ as.factor(gear) , scales = "free" )
```

[image]

While the percentages are correct in each facet, some of the fills are incorrect. My guess is there is a conflict between the `group` and `fill` options ?

Comment: It is easier to troubleshoot if you provide the code that you used while 'messing around' I can say for sure though that the grey color is the fill color for `NA` values.

Comment: Hi, the code I was 'messing around' with is above. I used the standard ```mtcars``` data set for this, it does not have any ```NA``` values. In cases where the values are missing as shown in the facets the graphs are empty,